# Why does Telerik RadDatePicker work in all browsers except in IE 9?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I use a Telerik control as DatePicker nl. RadDatePicker, the problem is that it doesn't work in IE 9.

This URL shows the main cause: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnetmvcteam/posts/10-05-03/internet-explorer-css-limits.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had also some issues with the telerik components in IE9 and in my case the solution was to upgrade to latest telerik library.

This is the risk when you use a propertary library...

Answer (score 0):

As of my personal experience I noticed that the Browser Compatibility issues arises when we use the old Script Manager, I also faced lot of issues but get out of them now by using the following:

1-RadScriptManager
2-RadAjaxManager
3-RadStyleSheetManager

For RadScriptManager load the script library in it rather than relying on the the controls Embeded themes:

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" 
    EnableTheming="True">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" 
            Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" 
            Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" 
            Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
    </Scripts>
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

Also a helpful link about the library loading see following:
[enter link description here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-disabling-embedded-resources.html)

Thanks Everyone!
Yasir Ali
From Islamabad, Pakistan